# Build problem: APK not produced, "Nothing to pre compile!"

Tags: android

I compiled my application, and it used to work fine. When I build normally it creates an APK file in the bin folder. Now, nothing.

```
[2010-11-30 12:06:58 - MyProject] Removing generated java classes.
[2010-11-30 12:06:58 - MyProject] Refreshing resource folders.
[2010-11-30 12:06:58 - MyProject] Starting full Pre Compiler.
[2010-11-30 12:06:58 - MyProject] Removing generated java classes.
[2010-11-30 12:06:58 - MyProject] Preparing generated java files for update/creation.
[2010-11-30 12:06:58 - MyProject] C:\dev\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-4\tools\aapt.exe package -m -v -J C:\svn\MyProject\gen -M C:\svn\MyProject\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\svn\MyProject\res -I C:\dev\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-4\android.jar 
[2010-11-30 12:06:58 - MyProject] Locale/Vendor pairs:
[2010-11-30 12:06:58 - MyProject]    /
[2010-11-30 12:06:58 - MyProject]    /
[2010-11-30 12:06:58 - MyProject]    /
[2010-11-30 12:06:58 - MyProject]    /
[2010-11-30 12:06:58 - MyProject] 
[2010-11-30 12:06:58 - MyProject] Files:
... truncated ...
[2010-11-30 12:06:58 - MyProject]       Src: C:\svn\MyProject\res\values\strings.xml
[2010-11-30 12:06:58 - MyProject]   xml\settings.xml
[2010-11-30 12:06:58 - MyProject]       Src: C:\svn\MyProject\res\xml\settings.xml
[2010-11-30 12:06:58 - MyProject]   AndroidManifest.xml
[2010-11-30 12:06:58 - MyProject]       Src: C:\svn\MyProject\AndroidManifest.xml
[2010-11-30 12:06:58 - MyProject] Including resources from package: C:\dev\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-4\android.jar
[2010-11-30 12:06:58 - MyProject] applyFileOverlay for drawable
[2010-11-30 12:06:58 - MyProject] applyFileOverlay for layout
[2010-11-30 12:06:58 - MyProject] applyFileOverlay for anim
[2010-11-30 12:06:58 - MyProject] applyFileOverlay for xml
[2010-11-30 12:06:58 - MyProject] applyFileOverlay for raw
[2010-11-30 12:06:58 - MyProject] applyFileOverlay for color
[2010-11-30 12:06:58 - MyProject] applyFileOverlay for menu
... truncated ...
[2010-11-30 12:06:58 - MyProject]   Writing symbols for class R.
[2010-11-30 12:06:58 - MyProject] Nothing to pre compile!
[2010-11-30 12:07:00 - MyProject] Refreshing resource folders.
[2010-11-30 12:07:00 - MyProject] Starting incremental Pre Compiler: Checking resource changes.
[2010-11-30 12:07:00 - MyProject] Nothing to pre compile!
```

Everything seems fine until the last line. Verbose is turned on.

Any idea what's wrong??

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting the project then cleaning, and reimporting it, fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me in conjunction with the issue where R as in R.drawable.* is not recognized.  I fixed it by removing the following import and cleaning my project.

```
import android.R;
```

Hopefully, that solves your issue too.